# How to identify null fields in a csv file?

Tags: arrays, scala, csv, apache-spark, mapping

I'm using Spark 2.1.1 and Scala 2.11.8.

I have to read data from a csv file with columns ranging from minimum 6 to maximum of 8. I have to split the 9 entries and once split, columns 0 to 5 will always have data. However data can either be present or absent in columns 6 to 8. I separated and stored the required columns in a RDD using:

```
val read_file = sc.textFile("Path to input file");

val uid = read_file.map(line => {var arr = line.split(","); (arr(2).split(":")(0),arr(3),arr(4).split(":")(0),arr(5).split(":")(0),arr(6).split(":")(0),arr(7).split(":")(0),arr(8).split(":")(0))})
```

Now, in the RDD 'uid' obtained, columns 0 to 3 will always be filled but 4 to 7 may or may not have data. Eg: The csv file from which I'm reading the data,

```
2017-05-09 21:52:42 , 1494391962 , p69465323_serv80i:10:450 , 7 , fb_406423006398063:396560, guest_861067032060185_android:671051, fb_100000829486587:186589, fb_100007900293502:407374, fb_172395756592775:649795

2017-05-09 21:52:42 , 1494391962 , z67265107_serv77i:4:45 , 2:Re , fb_106996523208498:110066, fb_274049626104849:86632, fb_111857069377742:69348, fb_127277511127344:46246

2017-05-09 21:52:42 , 1494391962 , v73392772_serv33i:9:1400 , 1:4x , c2eb11fd-99dc-4dee-a75c-bc9bfd2e0ae4iphone:314129, fb_217409795286934:294262
```

As it can be seen, the first entry has all 9 columns filled, the second entry has 8 filled and the 3rd entry has only 6 columns filled.

From the RDD obtained, I have to map column arr(1)(0) with columns arr(3)(0) to arr(7)(0).The mapping of column 1 should be done only with filled columns from 3 to 7. Empty columns between 3 to 7 do not have to be mapped with column 1. I was trying to do this using for loop:

Once I have this after executing the statement val uid = read_file.map():

```
(String, String, String, String, String, String, String) = (" p69465323_serv80i"," 7 "," fb_406423006398063"," guest_861067032060185_android"," fb_100000829486587"," fb_100007900293502"," fb_172395756592775")
```

I do:

```
for (var x <= 5 to 7) { if var arr => (arr(x) != null) {
val pairedRdd = uid.map(x => ((x._1, x._3), (x._1, x._4), (x._1, x._5), (x._1, x._6), (x._1, x._7)) ) }
```

This will work for the first statement in the example of the data given but not the second and third.

The logic is wrong, I admit but it's only to convey an idea of what I'm trying to do.

P.S : Use of Spark SQL is not allowed.

Comment: The missing columns, are they in order? I mean when, say, one column is missing, the column number is column 7, right?

Comment: Correct. Missing columns will always be in order.

Comment: You have 9 columns. can you please review your question an update incorrect info ?

Comment: Done. I've mentioned that columns are starting from 0 in the second line itself. Columns are from 0-8.

Comment: sample of your required output should also help :)

Comment: The output would be something like ((String, String), (String, String), (String, String), (String, String)) = ((" p69465323_serv80i"," fb_406423006398063"),(" p69465323_serv80i"," guest_861067032060185_android"),(" p69465323_serv80i"," fb_100000829486587"),(" p69465323_serv80i"," fb_100007900293502")) which further has be used for another mapping which I'm still trying to figure out how to do

Comment: If you observe, all 4 tuples in column one have the same first entry. It's the second entry that's differing @ Ramesh Maharjan

Comment: @QueepyDev Why are you using RDDs?! It's 21st century :) Use Spark SQL. That would be a no-brainer.

Comment: @ Jacek Laskowski I totally agree with you. The model we're working on requires Spark models both with SQL and Scala. I have been assigned the Scala part. So what actually is very easy in Spark SQL has to be converted to Scala as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following

```
val read_file = sc.textFile("Path to input file")
val uid = read_file.map(line => line.split(",")).map(array => array.map(arr => {
    if(arr.contains(":")) (array(2).split(":")(0), arr.split(":")(0))
    else (array(2).split(":")(0), arr)
}))
```

Now doing

```
uid.map(array => array.drop(2)).map(array => array.toSeq)
```

would give you `rdd` as

```
WrappedArray(( p69465323_serv80i, p69465323_serv80i), ( p69465323_serv80i, 7 ), ( p69465323_serv80i, fb_406423006398063), ( p69465323_serv80i, guest_861067032060185_android), ( p69465323_serv80i, fb_100000829486587), ( p69465323_serv80i, fb_100007900293502), ( p69465323_serv80i, fb_172395756592775))
WrappedArray(( z67265107_serv77i, z67265107_serv77i), ( z67265107_serv77i, 2), ( z67265107_serv77i, fb_106996523208498), ( z67265107_serv77i, fb_274049626104849), ( z67265107_serv77i, fb_111857069377742), ( z67265107_serv77i, fb_127277511127344))
WrappedArray(( v73392772_serv33i, v73392772_serv33i), ( v73392772_serv33i, 1), ( v73392772_serv33i, c2eb11fd-99dc-4dee-a75c-bc9bfd2e0ae4iphone), ( v73392772_serv33i, fb_217409795286934))
```

Whereas doing

```
uid.map(array => array.drop(2)).flatMap(array => array)
```

would give you `rdd` as

```
( p69465323_serv80i, p69465323_serv80i)
( p69465323_serv80i, 7 )
( p69465323_serv80i, fb_406423006398063)
( p69465323_serv80i, guest_861067032060185_android)
( p69465323_serv80i, fb_100000829486587)
( p69465323_serv80i, fb_100007900293502)
( p69465323_serv80i, fb_172395756592775)
( z67265107_serv77i, z67265107_serv77i)
( z67265107_serv77i, 2)
( z67265107_serv77i, fb_106996523208498)
( z67265107_serv77i, fb_274049626104849)
( z67265107_serv77i, fb_111857069377742)
( z67265107_serv77i, fb_127277511127344)
( v73392772_serv33i, v73392772_serv33i)
( v73392772_serv33i, 1)
( v73392772_serv33i, c2eb11fd-99dc-4dee-a75c-bc9bfd2e0ae4iphone)
( v73392772_serv33i, fb_217409795286934)
```

The choice is yours

Comment: That's close to what I'm looking for  but the output of uid.first() statement I mentioned above is the RDD I'm looking to perform the operation on, i.e the first column of uid RDD is mapped to columns 4th to 7th provided they are not null. Null columns just have to be skipped. Also, this mapping has to be performed on over 50 million entries with number of  columns varying in each entry. That's why I tried to use the looping mechanism.

Comment: so you want only the outputs that have 9 fields, is that right?

Comment: No no, the output I'm getting in the UID RDD, columns 3 and 4 will always be filled. Columns 5 to 7 can either be filled or empty. I have to map the first column with as many columns available from 3 - 7 say, if only column 3,4,5 are filled, I have to map column 1 to column 3,4,5. If column 3,4,5,6,7 are filled, I have to map column 1 with 3,4,5,6,7 and so on. I have to check for null columns from 5 to 7 in each entry. If null, I don't map with column 1. If not null, I map with column 1. But no entry is to be omitted, all of them have to be mapped. I hope that conveys what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: so it means that if 5 to 7 are null then you get (array(1), array(1)) for each 5 to 7, is that so?

Comment: Say I got ("p","7","fb1","fb2","fb3","fb4","fb5"). Now columns 3 to 7 are not blank so I map column (1,3);(1,4);(1,5);(1,6);(1,7). But if column 5,6,7 are null, I map (1,3);(1,4). If column 7 is null, I map (1,3);(1,4);(1,5);(1,6) and so on.

Comment: isn't my answer the same ? You are confusing me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148036/discussion-between-avi-aggarwal-and-ramesh-maharjan).